# How to select dynamic id generated by php script

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

It's weird but I found all article not working for me.  I have ids in my forms like formup_1, formup_2 generated by PHP scripts.  Now I'm not able to select a particular id.  How can I do that. Do I have to use live for binding event?

I tried to do it like this:

```
var vvv=$("form[id^='rating_formup_']");


<form id="rating_formup_1">
<input type="submit" name="n" value="">
</form>
<form id="rating_formup_2">
<input type="submit" name="n" value="">
</form>
.
.
.
```

Comment: Why did you prefix the id with `rating_`?

Comment: What do you do later with `vvv`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('form[id^="rating_formup_"]').foo();
```

It will select all the `<form>` elements that their `id` starts with `formup`

You can also use:

```
$('form').filter(function(){
    return /^rating_formup_/.test(this.id);
});
```

Which might be a little bit faster.

If you do that and it's still not working:

1. Check for typos.
2. Make sure the DOM is ready.
3. If the `<form>` are created on the fly, make sure you query the DOM **after** they are inserted to the DOM.

Comment: Note - OP edited the post, ids are now like `rating_formup_1`.

Comment: @BCT. Not this is my answer... `:)` Anyway, then you already attached to (some\all) of them event handlers, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: its not in working condition but i have put it on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bipin000/s8sPy/

Comment: @BCT. **1.** That has many syntax errors. **2.** it's a lot of code, can you narrow it down?

Answer (score 1):

Just try with this

```
$('form[id^="rating_formup_"]'); // select any form id start with rating_formup_
```

To bind event you can try

```
$('form[id^="rating_formup_"]').on('click', function() {
 // your stuff
});
```

**or**

```
$('form[id^="rating_formup_"]').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    // do something 
  });
});
```

#### Remainder

- recheck for typing errors
- don't forget to include jQuery library
- place your code within `$(document).ready(function() {...})` , in short `$(function() {..})`.

Comment: `$('form[id^=rating_formup_').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
  });
});` **is simply:** => `$('form[id^=rating_formup_').click(fn)`

Comment: @BCT. I actually this is not my answer... Anyway, then you already attach to (some\all) of them event handlers, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: guys thanks all of yours code works for me but it triggers the event twice i have used stopPropogation but still..